# Adding Form Values as Numbers and Floats with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read several posts/threads on adding form values but I'm missing something and could use some help.

I have three input text boxes.  I want to add the values in two of them to see if they match the value entered into the third.  Most of my tests are wrong whether I use whole or float numbers.  Sigh!

Code:

```
var payments_total = 0.00;
payments_total = Math.round(parseFloat($('#amount1').val())) + Math.round(parseFloat($('#amount2').val()));
if( payments_total == Math.round(parseFloat($('#answer').val())) ){
        alert("we have a match");
    } else {
        alert("no match");
    }
```

Would someone show me what I'm doing wrong? I need this to work for whole numbers and decimal numbers.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what are you entering? what is there in `$('#answer').val()`?

Comment: answer = 999.72, amount1 = 900.42, amount2 = 99.30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have either a precision or a rounding problem (or both).
To get right to the issue, try this:

```
var amount1 = parseFloat($('#amount1').val());
var amount2 = parseFloat($('#amount2').val());
var answer  = parseFloat($('#answer').val());

var payments_total = Math.round(amount1 + amount2);

console.log('amount1 = ' + amount1);
console.log('amount2 = ' + amount2);
console.log('answer = '  + answer);

if( payments_total == Math.round(answer) ){
    alert("we have a match");
} else {
    alert("no match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem, but probably not the only one as you say it doesn't work with integers is that you are adding rounded values:

```
payments_total = Math.round(parseFloat($('#amount1').val())) + Math.round(parseFloat($('#amount2').val()));
```

rather than rounding added values:

```
payments_total = Math.round(parseFloat($('#amount1').val())  + parseFloat($('#amount2').val());
```

e.g. for amount1 = 2.4 and amount2 = 3.2

the former would give the answer 2 + 3 = 5

the latter would give the answer 2.4 + 3.2 = round(5.6) = 6

Try printing out the relevant values in the 'alert' for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As per you comment, here is why

```
answer = Math.round(999.72) => 1000

amount1 = Math.round(900.42) => 900

amount2 = Math.round(99.30) => 99

So, 1000 != 999
```

Instead, you could do the addition before

`Math.round(999.72) = Math.round(900.42 + 99.30) = 1000`

Answer (score 0):

All numbers in javascript are `floats` so there is no need to use `Math.round()` afaics. `ParseFloat()` is required to convert the strings from the `<input>` elements to numbers (which will be stored as `floats` in variables):

```
var payments_total = parseFloat($('#amount1').val()) + parseFloat($('#amount2').val());
if( payments_total == parseFloat($('#answer').val()) ){
    alert("we have a match");
} else {
    alert("no match");
}
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/EneWOxe/2/edit

Every time a number is stored in a variable it will be converted to a float, so `Math.round()` is probably only required to prettify output.